# Variables called from methods not working

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a textbox effect for my RPG game, but I keep getting nullpointers because my variables are null, but I'm setting them in a method. I also need to be able to update the variables in the method, which isn't working.  That's why the NPE is occurring. Here is my code:

```
    package me.loafayyy.gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import me.loafayyy.main.RPG;
import me.loafayyy.main.RPGPane;
import me.loafayyy.main.RPGState;

public class GuiManager {

    public int opacity = 0;
    public int step = 0;
    public static boolean transitioning = false;
    public static boolean dialogue = false;
    public  String textlines1;
    public String textlines2;
    public String textlines3;

    public boolean rect = false;

    public Timer timer = new Timer();

    public void createTransition() {
        transitioning = true;
        rect = true;
    }

    public void setOpacity(int op) {
        opacity = op;
    }

    public int getOpacity() {
        return opacity;
    }

    public  void createDialogue(String line1, String line2, String line3, int dur) { // my method which I'm setting the variables.
        if (!dialogue) {
            dialogue = true;
            this.textlines1 = line1;
            this.textlines2 = line2;
            this.textlines3 = line3;

            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialogue = false;
                }

            }, dur);
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("ERROR: Could not create dialogue, one is already displaying!");
        }
    }

    public void render(Graphics g) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (transitioning) {
                rect = false;
                if (step == 0) {
                    if (opacity < 255) {
                        setOpacity(getOpacity() + 1);
                    } else if (opacity == 255) {
                        step = 1;
                    }
                } else if (step == 1) {
                    if (opacity < 256 && opacity != 0) {
                        setOpacity(getOpacity() - 1);
                    } else if (opacity == 0) {
                        transitioning = false;
                        step = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (transitioning) {
            if (RPG.state == RPGState.MAIN) {
                RPGPane.main.render(g);
            } else if (RPG.state == RPGState.PAUSED) {
                RPGPane.paused.render(g);
            } else if (RPG.state == RPGState.INGAME) {
                RPGPane.ingame.render(g);
            }
            g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, getOpacity()));
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, RPG.getWidth(), RPG.getHeight());
        }

        if (RPG.state == RPGState.INGAME) {
            if (dialogue) {
                g2.drawString(textlines1, 300, 300); // <--- null right here
                // do other textlines
            }
        }
    }
}
```

New code:

```
  package me.loafayyy.gui;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import me.loafayyy.main.RPG;
import me.loafayyy.main.RPGPane;
import me.loafayyy.main.RPGState;

public class GuiManager {

    public int opacity = 0;
    public int step = 0;
    public static boolean transitioning = false;
    public static boolean dialogue = false;
    public  String textlines1;
    public String textlines2;
    public String textlines3;

    public boolean rect = false;

    public Timer timer = new Timer();

    public GuiManager () {
        textlines1 = "";
    }

    public void createTransition() {
        transitioning = true;
        rect = true;
    }

    public void setOpacity(int op) {
        opacity = op;
    }

    public int getOpacity() {
        return opacity;
    }


    public void render(Graphics g) {

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (transitioning) {
                rect = false;
                if (step == 0) {
                    if (opacity < 255) {
                        setOpacity(getOpacity() + 1);
                    } else if (opacity == 255) {
                        step = 1;
                    }
                } else if (step == 1) {
                    if (opacity < 256 && opacity != 0) {
                        setOpacity(getOpacity() - 1);
                    } else if (opacity == 0) {
                        transitioning = false;
                        step = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        if (transitioning) {
            if (RPG.state == RPGState.MAIN) {
                RPGPane.main.render(g);
            } else if (RPG.state == RPGState.PAUSED) {
                RPGPane.paused.render(g);
            } else if (RPG.state == RPGState.INGAME) {
                RPGPane.ingame.render(g);
            }
            g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, getOpacity()));
            g2.fillRect(0, 0, RPG.getWidth(), RPG.getHeight());
        }

        if (RPG.state == RPGState.INGAME) {
            if (dialogue) {
                g2.drawString(textlines1, 300, 300);
                // do other textlines
            }
        }
    }

    public  void createDialogue(String line1, String line2, String line3, int dur) {
        if (!dialogue) {
            dialogue = true;
            this.textlines1 = line1;
            this.textlines2 = line2;
            this.textlines3 = line3;

            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    dialogue = false;
                }

            }, dur);
        } else {
            System.out
                    .println("ERROR: Could not create dialogue, one is already displaying!");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm calling this from another class using this:

```
mng.createDialogue("test1", "test2", "test3", 1000);
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-10" java.lang.NullPointerException: String is null
at sun.java2d.SunGraphics2D.drawString(Unknown Source)
at me.loafayyy.gui.GuiManager.render(GuiManager.java:98)
at me.loafayyy.main.RPGPane.render(RPGPane.java:107)
at me.loafayyy.main.RPGPane.run(RPGPane.java:82)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

RPGPane is my JPanel.

Comment: Why don't you just initialize them when you declare them? `public String textlines1 = "";`

Comment: Where do you get the NPE?

Comment: @tieTYT scroll down to the bottom of the code and it's right there ;)

Comment: @Takendarkk if I initialize it, whatever I initialize there it what appears on screen :/

Comment: @LoafOfCat what is your stack trace?

Comment: posted stacktrace in the post

Comment: Why are `dialogue` and `transitioning` declared `static`? If these were per-instance, then your `if (dialogue)` condition in `render` might make more sense and keep the NPE from happening. As it stands, `createDialogue` assigns to the strings and sets `dialogue`--this should probably happen on a per-instance basis.

Comment: This isn't a minimal example.  Can you start from scratch and reproduce just enough to show the sort of code that causes the problem?  Or pare this down until all that's left is the code that's causing the problem?

Comment: The problem is that the variables values are not changing publicly, and that's what I need them to do.  All I'm asking for is a simple reason why they're not updating.  If you could tell me, it would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your `render` method can be called before your `createDialogue` method.  As a result, `textlines1` can be unassigned/null.

One way to solve this is to take @Takendarkk's advice and initialize the variable to "".  Another way is to ask yourself, "Does it make sense for this class to exist without `textlines1` being set?  If not, perhaps set this in the `GuiManager`'s constructor.

Comment: if I initilize textlines1 to nothing, it's obviously just going to draw nothing on the screen error-free.  The problem is, the variable isn't being set, therefore it being a nullpointer.  If I initialize it to "", it won't help solve my problem :/

Comment: Well it's not being set because the NPE.  If you avoided the NPE, it would eventually get set to whatever you pass into `createDialogue`.  Have you *tried* setting it to "" to see what happens?  What happens?

Comment: I tested it, and set it to "".  It just draws nothing, because it's drawing ""  I'm also setting it in the constructor.  I'll update the code right now.

Comment: @LoafOfCat what happens if you set it to a value like, "Foo" in the constructor?  Does it print "Foo"?

Comment: @LoafOfCat You might not get the results you were hoping for, but declaring/initializing the String in the beginning will indeed solve the NPE which is what the question was about.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, what I'm really trying to do is to be able to set textlines1 etc. from a method.  They should be changing, but for some reason they aren't.

Comment: i have to say @tieTYT seems right.  The only way you are calling the method is outside of the class, which has already passed by the g2.drawstring part once instantiated.

Comment: the render(Graphics g) method is being called 60 times per second, so I would issume that it would update it...

Comment: @tieTYT yes, it does print foo, but I have no way of setting it to something besides foo because it isn't working ;/